# How can I transition between two shapes?

Tags: animation

What would be the best way to animate a smooth transition between a mostly normal hand and a large blade? (The blade is part of the arm.) Something like clayface or prototype?

Comment: I tried editing this but it is still a bit localized. Try to be as specific as possible in your requests and keep posts limited to one topic/question. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you mean by "a quick movement kind of like water"?

Comment: Would you mind moving the water question to a different post? That way, we can focus on that question by itself.

Comment: Concerning the water part, I do not think it is supposed to be a different question, I think he wants the 'transition' to act like water... Or something like that.

Comment: Including a picture or a drawing of what you are trying to do would probably help a lot.

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend using shape keys. Shape keys will warp between one shape to another.

To use shape keys. Create the default mesh, then go to edit mode and scroll down to the shape keys section. Click the plus and model the blade(make sure to use the same vertices as the hand model). Exit edit mode, and drag the influence slider to change the shape.

Comment: would have been my first guess aswell. But what could you do if the hand is already modeled and you still need the blade? BTW [here](http://cgcookie.com/blender/2010/11/09/creating-a-werewolf-part-3/) is a nice tut I used for that