# Is it possible to interpolate between two different meshes?

Tags: animation

Lets say that mesh 1 is Suzanne
And mesh 2 is also suzanne but the vertices are moved around alot

Can I tell blender to make Suzanne 1 to morph into suzanne 2?

Edit:

I heard I can do it with shapekeys if I "model it" in edit mode.
But the thing is, its already modeled, its just a different mesh.

Seems like a waste of effort to remodel what is already modeled.

Is it possible to do it without manually re-modeling mesh number one?

Comment: Possible dupe https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/899/how-can-i-transition-between-two-shapes?

Comment: im trying to interpolate between two separate meshes

Comment: Maybe http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/34758/12 then

Comment: mmm, yes, this is what I was looking for. Thank You